# Stop bind "blur" if click on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

My bind function:

```
$searchInput.bind('blur', function() {
  $searchResults.remove();
}
```

But this shouldn't happen if I click on a link inside of `$searchResults`. Now `$searchResults` is removed before I can click on a link.
How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply set a flag on mouse over `$searchResults`:

```
var isOver = false;
$searchInput.bind("blur", function(e) {
    if (!isOver) {
        $searchResults.remove();
    }
});

$searchResults.hover(function() {
    isOver = true;
}, function() {
    isOver = false;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/sUA4D/

You can do the same via element data, e.g. setting `$searchResults.data("isOver", true)`.

Answer (score 1):

One option that comes to mind is to delay the execution of the `$.remove()` call, like this:

```
$searchInput.bind('blur', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $searchResults.remove();
    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchInput.find('a').on('click', function() {
  $searchResults.remove();
});
```

Comment: The link is not in an input element :P